# xpath group by "name" field

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a XML which is a list of event thresholds, I would like get this data binding on the "name" of the threshold, so I can then get the associated keys and values for a specific "named" event threshold.

Non-working code:

```
      NodeList events = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("event/event-thresholds/name/text()", data, XPathConstants.NODESET);

      for (Node event : asList(events)) {
        logger.info("Event: " + event.getParentNode().getNodeName() + ":" + event.getNodeValue());

        NodeList e2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("event[event-thresholds/@name = " +  event.getNodeValue() + "]/text()", data, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (Node e : asList(e2)) {
          logger.info(e.getTextContent());
        }

      }
```

I have the following XML:

```
        <event>
        <event-thresholds>
          <name>bind-count</name>
          <set-value>800</set-value>
          <clear-value>600</clear-value>
          <set-percentage>80</set-percentage>
          <clear-percentage>60</clear-percentage>
        </event-thresholds>
        <event-thresholds>
          <name>spool-usage</name>
          <set-value>3200</set-value>
          <clear-value>2400</clear-value>
          <set-percentage>80</set-percentage>
          <clear-percentage>60</clear-percentage>
          </event-thresholds>
        <event-thresholds>
       </event>
```

for the output, I'm trying to iterate over event-thresholds, then send the "name" along with the values as a JSON object. e.g.

```
{
    "name": "spool-usage",
    "data": {
        "set-value": 3200,
        "clear-value": 1000,
        ...
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
      NodeList events = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("event/event-thresholds[name]", data, XPathConstants.NODESET);

      for (Node event : asList(events)) {
        logger.info(event.getUserData("name"));
        logger.info(event.getFirstChild().getNodeName());
        logger.info(event.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        logger.info(event.getNodeName());
        logger.info(event.getNodeValue());
        logger.info(event.getLocalName());
        logger.info(event.getTextContent());
      }
```

Yields:

```
5983 INFO  com.deblox.smg.QueueHandler:132 - NULL 
5984 INFO  com.deblox.smg.QueueHandler:133 - #text 
5984 INFO  com.deblox.smg.QueueHandler:134 - 

5984 INFO  com.deblox.smg.QueueHandler:135 - event-thresholds 
5984 INFO  com.deblox.smg.QueueHandler:136 - NULL 
5984 INFO  com.deblox.smg.QueueHandler:137 - NULL 
5984 INFO  com.deblox.smg.QueueHandler:138 - 
bind-count
800
600 
80
60
```

So I never seem to get the "name" attribute except for when getTextContent() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath query should be something like
`event/event-thresholds[name]`, and you will get the `event-thresholds` node.

You can see examples on this link:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/
see section 3.4

Comment: Progress, but I don't know how to get the "name" key value by its keyName. Since I can't assume the firstChild will always be the name?

Comment: You will need to iterate over the children nodes and lookup the nodes you want ('name', 'set-value', ...).

Comment: I added some Update above, even when iterating over the elements, none of them contain the "name" except for the getTextContent() which contains everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//event-thresholds").evaluate(data, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);

    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int j=0; j<childNodes.getLength(); ++j) {
        Node child = childNodes.item(j);
        System.out.println(child.getNodeName() + " - " + child.getTextContent());
    }
}
```